# How to get duplicate field values in elastic search by field name without knowing its value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field "EmployeeName" in an elastic search index - and I would like to execute a query that will return me all the cases where there are duplicate values of "EmployeeName". Can this be done?

I found more_like_this but this requires field value for "like_text".
But my requirement is to get  list of employees who are having duplicate names without knowing its value.

```
{
    "more_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["EmployeeName"],
        "like_text" : "Mukesh",
        "min_term_freq" : 1,
        "max_query_terms" : 12
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Regards
Mukesh

Comment: How does the mapping of `EmployeeName` look like? Is it `not_analyzed` or is it a multi-field with a `not_analyzed` sub-field? Can you change your mapping in that sense? If that's the case, see @Jettro comment below, you can use a `top_hits` sub-aggregation to get your duplicate documents.

Comment: Thanks for reply
in mapping EmployeeName is not_analyzed and I also got the result inside aggregations.Now I will try to get the documents for that result.
Thanks again

Comment: HI Val,

Can you please give me an example for top_hits.
I tried with this but under aggregations I am getting different document value for duplicate names and getting different documents under top_hits.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`Terms Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for this.

```
POST <index>/<type>/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "duplicateNames": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "EmployeeName",
                "size": 0,
                "min_doc_count": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will return all values of the field `EmployeeName` which occur in at least 2 documents.

Comment: It won't. `"min_doc_count": 2` ensures that it returns values that are duplicated. In the JSON response, you need to look at values inside `"aggregations"` object and not `"hits"` object.

Comment: Also note that 1) this method works only if `EmployeeName` is `not_analyzed` in your mapping and 2) you won't know which documents are duplicates, just that there are duplicates.

Comment: I agree with @Val you could use the top hits aggregation as a sub aggregation to the terms aggregation. That way the documents can be returned.

Comment: Thanks for reply

Yes you are right.I got the proper result under aggregations.
Now I will try to get document using top-hits for that result.

Thanks

Comment: HI Jettro,
 Can you please give me an example for top_hits. I tried with this but under aggregations I am getting different document value for duplicate names and getting different documents under top_hits. Thanks

Comment: What is size:0 for here ?

Comment: @h4ck3d `"size": 0` means return all possible values of the field "EmployeeName". Read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size

Comment: How do you use the top_hits, it seems to be very slow for big extractions.

Answer (score 16):

This would be the query with the current Elasticsearch version:

```
GET <index>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateNames": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "EmployeeName",
         "min_doc_count": 2
       }
     }
  }
}
```